# mod_python is not loading stackless Python

Tags: django, mod-python, python-stackless

I have setup an Apache2 mod_python environment with stackless Python and it is working.
And When I test the Python environment with `sys.version`, it shows

```
2.5.2 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (python-2.52:76701, Dec  8 2009, 02:13:34) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)]
```

in the browser.

But when I do `import stackless` it shows:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      26177
Interpreter:    '127.0.1.1'

ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www/'

URI:            '/test.py'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/var/www/'
Filename:       '/var/www/test.py'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 204, in handler
    module = page_cache[req]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1059, in __getitem__
    return import_module(req.filename)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 296, in import_module
    log, import_path)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 680, in import_module
    execfile(file, module.__dict__)

  File "/var/www/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stackless

ImportError: No module named stackless


MODULE CACHE DETAILS

Accessed:       Tue Dec  8 08:53:24 2009
Generation:     0

_mp_27cc55c5447f9e0aa13691719290c225 {
  FileName:     '/var/www/test.py'
  Instance:     1 [IMPORT]
  Generation:   0 [ERROR]
  Modified:     Tue Dec  8 08:52:43 2009
}
```

Also I am not able to load MySQLdb, nltk, etc. All these modules can be loaded in the commandline. So my guess is somehow mod_python is referring the old Python installation.

What could be the issue?

---

I have installed everything against stackless. As you can see my response for `sys.version` is

```
2.5.2 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (python-2.52:76701, Dec 8 2009, 02:13:34) [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)]
```

This is the response from the code:

```
import sys
def index(req):
  return sys.version
```

But when I add `import stackless` as below it throws the aforementioned error:

```
import sys
import stackless
def index(req):
  return sys.version
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Are there any differences in sys.path between Python instances launched from the command line and from mod_python? "ImportError: No module named ..." is usually caused by an incorrect PYTHONPATH setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_python is compiled against a specific version of Python, and will only call that version. You'll probably need to recompile it against Stackless, assuming that's possible.